# Any way to put Mac mini to sleep remotely?

Tags: ios, mac-mini, sleep-wake, remote-control

I use a Mac mini as a music centre connected to my stereo system (among other things). I control it remotely using apps such as [Remote](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/remote/id284417350?mt=8) by Apple, [Rowmote](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rowmote-remote-control-for/id300265786?mt=8), and [Remoteless](http://itunes.apple.com/fi/app/remoteless-for-spotify/id353392482?mt=8) (for Spotify), both on my iPhone and iPad.

Now, when getting to sleep myself, I often want to stop music playback with the device closest to hand, usually iPhone. **One more thing I'd like to do remotely is put the Mac mini to sleep**. Any idea whether this is possible?

To clarify, I'm looking for an app or other **solution that works on iPhone / iPad** (with latest iOS, not jailbroken).

Comment: RowMote suppports sleep...

Comment: @mankoff: oh, it does? How? Post that as an answer (with some details) & I'll accept it.

Comment: I just don't find such option anywhere in Rowmote UI. Is it a Rowmote Pro feature?

Comment: Look at the RowMote store page description - `SLEEP AND WAKE: Put your Mac to sleep by holding the Play button for 3 seconds while controlling any Apple application, just like the hardware remote.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can do this with a hot-corner and the built-in VNC server. (You would need a VNC viewer for iOS, there are **LOTS** of them.

You could also create an applescript:
`tell application "System Events" to sleep`
and run it using the VNC connection.

---

Alternatively, you can turn on ssh, ssh in, and issue the command:
`pmset sleepnow` <sup><sub>(See the [pmset man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html))</sub></sup>
to put the mac to sleep.

This would require a ssh client for iOS. Again, there are a LOT of them. Personally, I have used iSSH, and it works fine.

---

As @mankoff stated in a comment, [RowMote](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rowmote-remote-control-for/id300265786?mt=8) states in it's store description:

> - SLEEP AND WAKE: Put your Mac to sleep by holding the Play button for 3 seconds while controlling any Apple application, just like the
>     hardware remote. Rowmote automatically wakes up sleeping machines
>     which are connected via Ethernet!

Comment: I already had iSSH installed so I tried logging in an running `pmset` – works nicely (but you have to type).  Anyway: thanks for teaching me how Rowmote works. Perfect! (And indeed, this works with regular Rowmote just fine; no Pro needed.)

Answer (score 4):

I use the following setup to sleep my Mac by using an iPhone:

- I created a AppleScript which sleeps the Mac
- Create a rule in Mail.app, which runs the AppleScript. (I use a specific Subject and from Address to activate the rule)
- Then on the iOS device, you just need to send a mail, as soon as the Mac receives the mail it will go to sleep

Advantage: You can put your Mac to sleep without the need to be in the same network

Disadvantage: It could take some minutes until the Mac receives the mail.

Comment: Hmm, not the simplest solution, but pretty creative :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use remote mouse
download this app on your iPhone and Mac
follow the instruction on the screen
now you can make your make sleep and more